# Ignoring <svg> line in ESlint?

Tags: eslint

Is there anyway for ESlint to stop showing errors and ignore  inline codes?.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/j5hker8965klw0p/Screenshot%202020-01-11%2011.44.56.png?dl=0

I want to use  inline and would love to keep it as inline instead of a formatted code to keep the code clean. But just for

Tried doing

```js
"vue/max-attributes-per-line": [
    "error",
    {
      "ignore": [ "svg" ]
    }
],
```

But ESlint error still keeps showing up.

many thanks for those who can help!

Answer (score 0):

I can´t see your link...

If you want to avoid showing erros on path attributes, try this:

The best solution for me is to use **ignorePattern** like this:

```
ignorePattern: 'd="([\\s\\S]*?)"'
```

You alway can check the documentation: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/max-len